# Подключить Базу Данных к Node.js без SQL

Tags: node.js, данные

Хочется разобраться в азах хранения информации на сервере, поэтому решил начать без всяких SQL. Раньше я хранил информацию на `LocalStorage` и по понятным соображениям эта технология не работает c Node.js
Я уже понял что при том минимализме, что я выбрал хранить информацию нужно в .txt или .JSON но я не могу заставить записать информацию в файл если это не момент запуска условного `node app.js` .

```
   const http = require ('http');
const fs = require('fs');

//localhost:3000
http.createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log('server work');
    let data = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
    // res.write('Hello World');
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    h1 {
    text-align: center;
    }
    form {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
    label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    }
    button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    button:hover {
    background: #0056b3;
    }
    #inventoryList {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Складской учет товаров</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Складской учет товаров</h1>
<form id="inventoryForm">
<label for="productName">Наименование товара:</label>
<select id="productName" required>
<option value="SSD 128GB">SSD 128GB</option>
<option value="SSD 256GB">SSD 256GB</option>
<option value="SSD 512GB">SSD 512GB</option>
</select>
<label for="quantity">Количество:</label>
<input type="number" id="quantity" required>
<label for="price">Цена:</label>
<input type="number" id="price" required>
<button type="submit">Добавить товар</button>
</form>
<div id="inventoryList"></div>
<div id="inventoryInfo"></div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Очень хочется по нажатии на кнопку `"Добавить товар"` записать и оставить данные для всех пользователей домашней сети. И заодно понять как работает запись в файл .txt или .JSON ... а может получится изменить DOM если Node.js это позволит. Если окажется , что никак не обойтись без MongoDB то это тоже будет ответом.)

Или другими словами нужен такой script.js который бы смог управлять внешним файлом .txt или .JSON при нажатии на кнопку `"Добавить товар"`

Comment: С фронта без бэка менять данные на серверной части не получится. Запускаете ноду, там создаете апи и при нажатии на фронте кнопки, передаете данные. Для удобства, подключите к ноде express.

Comment: У меня запускается под Node.js .  файл app.js запускающий "Ноду" имеется в вопросе.

Comment: Есть. Он только хтмл отдает. Вам в него надо дабавить ендпоинты, что бы с фронта, каким нибудь fetch ходить за данными и присылать их.  На клиенте организовать рендер полученных данных. Тут, как бы, в 2-5 строк кода не уложиться. Надо пару статей пересказать. Посмотрите в сторону express, для быстрого создания роутов

Comment: Спасибо. А не сложно записать как это реализовать в Express ?

Comment: Можно. [Вот тут вчера как раз показывал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1571780/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2-json/1571789#1571789). Там с преобразованием, но не суть, вам подходит.

Comment: Посмотрел не увидел ни эндпоинта ни роута. Я в этом деле новичок. Но все равно спасибо. Вдруг придет озарение )))

Comment: Я же говорю, поставьте express, это снизит трудозатраты. 30 минут чтения про экспресс и вам придет все нужное озарение. [Ну вот для примера](https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/4.1.php)

Comment: Пример про Express, но он не дает ответа на мой вопрос. Отрисовать страницу и даже через / добавить внутри нее страницу я могу и без Express. А ты говорил про эндпоинты.. чем они отличаются в Express, что поможет создать Базу Данных ?

Comment: Да мой код отдает HTML - может есть возможность в DOM положить информацию из JSON ?

Comment: Поставьте nuxt или next если не хотите в этом разбираться

Comment: Не совсем понятно как именно Express решает данную проблему.  Но буду изучать Express подробнее.